# New dataframe column that looks for value in a row and returns value from another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe and need to create a new column that returns a value from a row beneath the current row and in a different column.  Below is the dataframe:

```
 event        event time  
 pass            10.10  
 failed block    10.20
 failed check    10.21  
 reception       10.25
 pass            17.60
 reception       17.65
```

I need to create a column called reception time.  Reception time will look for the first instance of reception after each pass and return the event time of the reception as shown below:

```
 event         event time   reception time  
 pass            10.10          10.25  
 failed block    10.20            NA
 reception       10.25            NA  
 pass            17.60          17.65  
 reception       17.65            NA
```

There could be 50 or more lines in between pass and reception.

I'm new to Python and can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Is there always only one `reception` between two `pass`?

Comment: btw, why is the 'failed check' absent from the output? is this a mistake?

Comment: @mozway you are correct, that was an oversight on my part

Comment: @It_is_Chris there actually could be more than one in some instances, I just need the next one regardless of the number.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two masks, [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['reception time'] = (df['event time']
                          .where(df['event'].eq('reception'))
                          .bfill()
                          .where(df['event'].eq('pass'))
                       )
```

output:

```
          event  event time  reception time
0          pass       10.10           10.25
1  failed block       10.20             NaN
2  failed check       10.21             NaN
3     reception       10.25             NaN
4          pass       17.60           17.65
5     reception       17.65             NaN
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks for your help!!